# form inputs and table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As a Begineer in a react, I am having a problem in aligning a select field and three input form fields in an inline row and wrapping above fields inside table having equal inputs field length and it looks like a table?

**code**

```
 <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <select
              value={values}
            >
              </select>
         
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <input 
                  type="text" 
                  value={name} 
 
              />
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <input
                type="number" 
                  value={number} 
              />
          </div>
//delete icon from materail-icons
          <Controls.ActionButton
                       color="secondary"
                      onhover="open"
                    >
                      <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
                    </Controls.ActionButton>
        </div>

 i want to wrap above input field into these table:
//material tables
 <TableContainer>
                              <Table stickyHeader>
                                <TableHead>
                                  <TableRow>
                                    <TableCell>CollegeName</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>name</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>number</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Actions</TableCell>
                                  </TableRow>
                                  </TableHead>
                                <TableBody>
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you've written for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need a grid-system, e.g. [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)

Es:

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>1 of 2</Col><Col>1 of 2</Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Col>1 of 2</Col><Col>1 of 2</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

With some style, es:

```
input, select { width:100%; }
```

If you post your code you can obtain a better help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use flexbox ([cheatsheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) for the grid system.

There's only a few properties you can play with. The ones useful for you in my opinion :

- flex-direction,
- justify-content,
- align-items.

For example :

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div className="row">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

With this scss

```
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    input {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
}
```

}

And if you want to learn this grid system by playing a few minutes : [Flexbox froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#fr).

For the select component, if you're using (for example let's say) react-select wrappred in a react-hook-form controller, then you can just add a style property that specifies the height. This way, everything is aligned.